# How to link a directory A to /var/www/root like below?

Tags: linux, bash

[image]

How to do the trick?

**UPDATE**

I did `ln -s A /var/www/root` by mistake,how to undo it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [ln](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) command to create a link. By default such a link is a hard link. Since you cannot create a hard link to a directory you need to create a symbolic link by using the `-s` option.

```
ln -s /var/www/root A
```

Comment: I did `ln -s A /var/www/root` by mistake,how to undo it?

Comment: There is no way to undo it. Your command will add a symlink to `A` (even if such a file/dir exists or not) in the dir `/var/www/root` as `A`. You can just delete that file as `rm /var/www/root/A`

Answer (score 1):

So, try: `ln -s /var/www/root A`

Answer (score 0):

Use a symbolic link:

`ln -s /var/www/root A`